GCP BiqQuery Splt String Between Two Characters
I need all the information between the colon and the comma wherever it appears in the string and after the last colon so it picks up that last bit of information.
Can someone help by using the field names.  The information in the string will change.
InputFieldNameA:
Cooperativ:Cooperative,Asks ques:Asks questions,Eager:Eager to learn
OutputNewFieldNameA:
Cooperative,Asks questions,Eager to learn
STRING_AGG(split(InputFieldNameA,":")[SAFE_OFFSET(1)],',') as OutputNewFieldNameA - Does Not Work
regexp_extract(InputFieldNameA, r":([^/$]?),.") as OutputNewFieldNameA  - Does Not Work (Need it to repeat)
